# JDBC connection to Microsoft SQL Server doesn't reconnect

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I have a database that is connected through an unreliable network connection to an application server, so occasionally the connections break down. Each time this happens, all database connections in the AP pool will need to reconnect - which they don't unfortunately.

I went through different setups of c3p0, dbcp and bonecp as pools and used JTDS as well as the SQL Server V3 driver, (I even ditched pooling atogether to try out whether the regular DataSource would be able to create a new unpooled connection - which it didn't) but all configuration variants don't seem able to recover after network failure.

To clarify, none of the DataSources were able to get a new Connection. Is there some inherent Problem with the MS Sql Server regarding reconnects? Am I missing something fundamental here?

I realize this might not be of big help, but just as an example this is the dbcp configuration

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.databaseurl}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriodInMinutes" value="1" />
    <property name="idleMaxAgeInMinutes" value="1" />
    <property name="maxConnectionsPerPartition" value="3" />
    <property name="minConnectionsPerPartition" value="1" />
    <property name="partitionCount" value="1" />
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="5" />
    <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="50" />
    <property name="acquireRetryDelayInMs" value="1000" />
    <property name="queryExecuteTimeLimitInMs" value="5000" />
    <property name="connectionTestStatement" value="SELECT count(*) FROM dbo.sysobjects" />
    <property name="closeConnectionWatch" value="true" />
    <property name="lazyInit" value="false" />
    <property name="statementsCacheSize" value="100" />
    <property name="releaseHelperThreads" value="3" />
</bean>
```

Comment: The sample doesn't seem to be for dbcp. For dbcp you need to setup testOnBorrow / testOnIdle to true with the validationQuery.

Comment: You are right. It's BoneCP of course. Though I did enable testOnBorrow, testOnIdle in the dbcp configuration.

Comment: Need to know what handled error messages point to network unreliability. MS SQL Server does not understand what a "reconnect" means. Under really bad situations MS SQL Server can go deaf - your sysadmin can assist.

How long does a network outage last? You could poll netstat on the boxes, or you could concurrently collect two network sniffs. Your configuration appears to stop retrying after 50 seconds, so netstat's polling interval needs to be shorter than 1/3rd of 50 seconds, or the sniffs need to buffer ~150 seconds worth of traffic, or the number of reties needs to be increased.

Comment: Avoid wiring up the connection to consumers. Instead provide a factory to the consumers of the connection.The consumers can release the connection as soon as they are done with it. Therefore a single failed connection will fail the method call. The next call will open a new connection.